Calculate difference in 2 columns using criteria in another

Hello,
Looking to create formula to calculate  how many or percentage of
(NOTE: assuming static -+1 , everything else is either improvement or regression)

improved based on coaching?
didn’t improve despite coaching
regressed despite coaching?
static despite conversation?

[Sample attached as image]
Thanks


You forgot to mention how the output should look like or that it should include or exclude the non-coaching values. This may help you on the right track: =LET(x,B2:B9-A2:A9,FILTER((ABS(x)>1%)*SIGN(x),C2:C9="Yes"))

Please read https://superuser.com/tour @ Improve posts by editing or commenting - comments is not for answers. Write a full answer instead.

@hannu is that directed to my comment? If I don't know what's asked I can't tell it answers the question.

So, what have you tried?
SuperUser is not a formula writing service, but here, a little help forward...
The table you provided:
1. improved based on coaching?  
2. didn’t improve despite coaching  
3. regressed despite coaching?  
4. static despite conversation?  

... should be a good start;
just add a new column where you fill in wording for how W41, W42 and Coaching
determines the above 'Status' Tip: AND(... , ...).
It shouldn't be hard to "translate" those to Excel/Spreadsheet formulas; as they will be building blocks for what you're asking for. Tip: IF(Status,"True-Text","False-Text")
